# Subtract maximum per row

Tags: r, matrix, max, vectorization

Suppose you want to subtract the maximum value of each row of a matrix from the respective row. You could do it using a loop like this:

```
# create matrix
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=5,nrow=20)

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){    #for each row
  row.max <- max( mat[i,] ) #take the maximum of the row
  mat[i,] <- mat[i,] - row.max  #subtract it from the row
}
```

I am thinking about a way to do this in a vectorized manner, maybe using `max.col()` , however, I could not come up with something so far. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks for your answers, I accepted the (by far) fastest solution.

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
    loop 4671.687 4906.6820 5124.78995 5019.7965 5214.5935 12318.986   100
   apply   41.055   47.0430   60.58208   57.0925   71.6320   158.661   100
 rowMaxs    2.139    2.9945    6.21019    5.3465    8.9810    12.402   100
 do.call  111.618  125.0890  154.46904  142.4095  170.2065   422.522   100
```

Comment: One way could be `mat - apply(mat, 1, max)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `library(matrixStats)` and simply use,

```
mat - rowMaxs(mat)
```

---

As seen in row `matrixStats`, this solution is lightning-fast.(Benchmarking provided by *@hrbrmstr*)

```
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
##     base_mat  33.084  39.3215  46.93637  46.3575  49.6435  116.293   100
##      base_df  80.769  98.9870 116.05771 112.8985 127.6595  201.791   100
##  matrixStats   2.111   3.0170   4.99795   4.9655   5.8415   27.240   100
##    qlcMatrix 716.229 742.2140 834.73351 782.1605 888.4960 1491.734   100
```

Comment: Some of the `matrixStats` functions should become base functions. In `base` there is also a `max.col` that gives the index of the maximum value of each row, so a `rowMax` and `colMax` should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

A Base R option would be

```
mat - do.call(pmax, data.frame(mat))

 #           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
 #[1,] -2.6565620 -1.9266890 -1.3154080 -0.3471987  0.0000000
 #[2,]  0.0000000 -1.2758157 -0.7681151 -0.7530223 -1.3460720
 #[3,]  0.0000000 -1.8606951 -1.5249890 -1.7938812 -1.9398058
 #[4,] -2.8052871 -0.3951306  0.0000000 -0.9608475 -0.7402124
 #[5,] -0.5303694  0.0000000 -1.6532143 -2.5885875 -1.9538341
 #[6,]  0.0000000 -0.6163414 -1.9542608 -1.6736752 -1.4745702
 #[7,] -1.1494957 -1.0857652  0.0000000 -2.7547954 -1.6820739
 #[8,]  0.0000000 -0.3645636 -0.4770239 -0.7943613 -0.7053540
 #[9,] -0.5493137 -0.8220334  0.0000000 -0.2791556 -0.5086898
 #[10,] -3.3058730  0.0000000 -3.3517838 -2.8817327 -2.9126851
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=5,nrow=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `qlcMatrix` which has functions `rowMax;colMax;rowMin;colMin`.

Using this package you can do something of the form `mat - rowMax(mat)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sparse vector object that's returned by `qlcMatrix::rowMax()` cannot be subtracted from a matrix easily. It gives an `Error: not-yet-implemented method for -(<matrix>, <dsparseVector>).
 ->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.` error.

Comment: it's as easy as a call to `as.numeric()` which is in my not-an-answer-answer which I guess kind of is an answer now